# Python sys.stdout.flush() , flush every thing before it

Tags: python

I am new to python and i have a program witch is some king of showing percentage in the command line:

```
sys.stdout.write("[")

    for x in xrange(1,int(number)):

        percentage = (x*100)/int(number)
        numberfile.write(str(x)+'\n') 

        sys.stdout.write("\r%d%%" %percentage)
        sys.stdout.flush()

    sys.stdout.write("][Done]")
```

but my problem is the flush() function, delete all output before it and out put is something like this :

> 100%][Done]

How i can change it to

> [100%][Done]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is not the flush but the  "\r" in

```
sys.stdout.write("\r%d%%" %percentage)
```

Maybe you want

```
sys.stdout.write("\r[%d%%" %percentage)
```

Comment: the "\r" could not be deleted ,the output will mess up and cannot be replace by "\n" because i want output in the same line .

Answer (score 0):

```
    sys.stdout.write("\r%d%%" %percentage)
```

should be

```
    sys.stdout.write("\r[%d%%]" %percentage)
```

To avoid the funny display :

[Pseudo Code]

```
for x in xrange(1,int(number)):

    percentage = (x*100)/int(number)
    numberfile.write(str(x)+'\n') 

    lastP = percentage
    if (percentage  > lastP)
        sys.stdout.write("[%d%%]" %percentage);
        sys.stdout.flush();
        lastP = percentage
```

Comment: output bacame funny like:"[99%][99%][99%][99%][99%][99%][99%][99%][99%][99%][99%][99%][99%][99%][99%][99%][100%]][Done]"

Comment: you can either delay the disply or hold percent to another variable! print the percent only of current% > last% assuming that current & last are integer value!